# Google cloud deployment: How to reduce the file size of a .pbtxt?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to deploy a trained model to Google Cloud but I'm having trouble with the file size. Google Cloud has a 250mb file size limit. I was able to quantise the .pb file into a smaller size. Still, I don't know how to reduce the file size of the .pbtxt, is it possible to quantise the .pbtxt as well? If so, then how or is there any other method do reduce the size?

Thanks

Comment: You may contact google cloud ml team, asking to increase the cap for your project, with answering some questions.

Comment: I am going to assume that you are talking about saved_model.pb and saved_model.pbtxt file. Have you tried using saved_model.pb which should be smaller than its .pbtxt counterpart. If .pb is > 250 mb, then you can try reducing with techniques described here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models

Comment: @MatanHugi it is required by google cloud to have both

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Bhupesh, the service accepts both .pb and .pbtxt files; the former is a binary format and stored much more efficiently on disk.

Comment: So, I only need one of them? Cause I have both files but less than 250mb and I receive the following error: Field: version.deployment_uri Error: Deployment directory gs://fotologml/aesthet/ is expected to contain exactly one of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt]. so I thought I needed both of them.

Comment: @DanielZapata out of the list provided, you need to provide exactly one. So either the .pb or .pbtxt file.